# Trouble with long url (rewrite mod) subpages

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im looking for someone who will knowing the main code

I have subpages with ugly names [www.forexample.eu/index_pl.php?src=home](http://www.forexample.eu/index_pl.php?src=home) How cut it for this url [www.forexample.eu/start](http://www.forexample.eu/start)

Pls tell me how?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index_pl.php?src=home=$1&subpage=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^start index_pl.php?src=home [L]
```

If your link is `www.forexample.eu/start` it would load `www.forexample.eu/index_pl.php?src=home` 'in the back' but it would still show the first link.